# Problem with HiddenState declaration in LSTM

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I want to forecast multivariate (18) time series (sales) using one LSTM neural network using PyTorch framework. I have 16 features (lagged variables, prices, other factors for each) - overall 288.
Declaration of Classes looks like this:

```
class LSTMModel(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
            super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
            self.input_size = input_size
            self.hidden_size  = hidden_size
            self.output_size = output_size           
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_size, self.hidden_size, self.output_size, batch_first=True)
            self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.output_size)
           
        def forward(self, x):
            h0 = torch.zeros(1, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).requires_grad_()
            c0 = torch.zeros(1, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).requires_grad_()
            
            out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h0.detach_(), c0.detach_()))
            out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :]) 
            return out
```

Input_size here 288, hidden_size 96, output_size 18. Then I initialize my model:

```
hidden_size = 96
model = LSTMModel(X_all.shape[1], hidden_size, y_all.shape[1])
criterion = torch.nn.L1Loss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
```

Then I'm trying to train my model (batch_size is 100):

```
model.train()
epochs = 500

train_losses = []
for epoch in range(1, epochs):
    batch_losses = []
    iter = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        x_batch = x_batch.view([x_batch.shape[0], -1, X_all.shape[1]])        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        y_pred = model(x_batch)
        y_pred[y_pred < 0] = 0        
        loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y_train[iter*batch_size:min(iter*batch_size+batch_size, X_all.shape[0])])
        batch_losses.append(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        iter +=1
    training_loss = np.mean(batch_losses)
    print('Epoch {}: train loss: {}'.format(epoch, training_loss.item()))
    train_losses.append(training_loss)
    y_pred_train_n = y_pred.squeeze().detach().numpy()
```

And have a strange error in the following line:

```
out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h0.detach_(), c0.detach_()))
```

"RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (18, 826, 96), got [1, 826, 96]"

What am I doing wrong? From the documentation of pytorch LSTM:

h_0: tensor of shape (D * \text{num_layers}, N, H_{out})

I have 1 hidden layer, NN is not bidirectional, so first dim of hidden vector should be 1. Why 18?
If I change first dim in LSTM class declaration (18 instead of 1), then it works. What is the problem?

Comment: What is your input sequence lenght? From your question description I could only get input features as 288, hidden size as 96, and output sequence length as 18.

Comment: Good question... Seems to be that I didn't understand the work of model, and in my example input sequence length equal to 1. Is it fatal error?

Comment: LSTM is generally used for a sequence of timestep as input, so that we can use learning from previous timesteps (hidden and cell state) to calculate future sequences. For example looking at last 12 months sales data/features we might be interested in forecasting next 18 months data. In that case input sequence leangth would be 12 and output 18. In your case you are looking at one data point to forecast 18 future data points. In your case you can probably take outputs(hidden/cell state) from first input timestep and input it to the next timesteps to generate next 17 outputs.

Comment: This is not a fatal error. Look for variable input/output sequnce LSTM models and you can model your problem accordingly if it makes logical sense.

Comment: OK, got it. But what if I want to predict not sales for next 18 months (sequential data), but sales of let's say 18 different goods for next month? (this is the task)? How to organize data in that case?